# Trivial issue with React setState function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am actually at a loss to figure out why this isn't working as I have spent a lot more hours than usual on how to get it fixed. The problem is I am using axios to make a REST call to get the data to be rendered. Inside the block to handle the response, even though I am able to retrieve the data the 'this' object somehow fails to refer to the correct object and I get an error. I dono why this is happening but any help on it will be highly appreciated.

Posting my code snippet below. I have tried saving the context of this outside the axios call scope and used the new variable but that too does not help. Here is the error I get in my console

> TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

import './RouteList.css';

class RouteList extends Component{
constructor(){
    super();        
    this.setState = {
        allRoutes: {},
        selectedRoutes: {}
    };
    }    

componentDidMount(){
    const that = this;
    //Retrieve the SF-Muni route list        
    axios.get('http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicJSONFeed?command=routeList&a=sf-muni')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            that.setState({ allRoutes: response.data.routes });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });            
}

render(){
    return (
        <div className="transit-routes">
            {/*TODO-Code to render data.*/}
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default RouteList;`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the `setState` method in the constructor, try to set the initial state like this:

```
this.state = {
    allRoutes: {},
    selectedRoutes: {}
};
```

Also, when using an arrow function, there's no need to save the parent scope, the function will run under the same scope as the outer function.

Comment: Thanks a ton Crysfel.
Absolutely stupid of me to do a setState in the constructor.

Comment: hehehehe that happens to me when working long hours :) maybe you need a time to rest xD

Comment: Another minor thing -- if you do end up calling setState, make sure you call it as a method like this.setState({foo: bar}) rather than trying to set setState equal to something, which is what you are in effect doing by using the 'this.setState = {foo: bar}'